# машины не выходят с 0 по вертикали и с 0 по горизонатали. едут лишь с одной стороны дороги

Tags: python, pygame, координаты

делаю симулятор светофора. создал две полосы дороги одна вертикальная другая горизонтальная. хотел сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки vertical или horizontal с обеих частей дороги сответственно выходили машины и исчезали при границе. проблема в том что машины выходят лишь с конца горизонатали и вертикали и еще застрявают на границе.
вот код полный:

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 600
FPS=30
INTERSECTION_CENTER = (300, 200)
class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, direction):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))  
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.direction = direction

    def update(self):
        if self.direction == "vertical":
            if self.rect.y==0:
                self.rect.move_ip(0,5)
            elif self.rect.y==HEIGHT:
                self.rect.move_ip(0,-5)
            else:
                self.rect.move_ip(0,-5)
        elif self.direction == 'horizontal':
            if self.rect.x==0:
                self.rect.move_ip(5,0)
            elif self.rect.x==WIDTH:
                self.rect.move_ip(-5,0)
            else:
                self.rect.move_ip(-5,0)
def create_random_car(direction):
    if direction == 'vertical':
        x = random.randint(150, 450)
        y = random.choice([0, HEIGHT]) 
    elif direction == 'horizontal':
        x = random.choice([0, WIDTH])  
        y = random.randint(250, 350)
    
    car = Car(RED, x, y, direction)
    return car
def create_random_car(direction):
    if direction == 'vertical':
        x = random.randint(150, 450)
        y = random.choice([0, HEIGHT]) 
    elif direction == 'horizontal':
        x = random.choice([0, WIDTH])  
        y = random.randint(250, 350)
    
    car = Car(RED, x, y, direction)
    return car
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('inter')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if 10 <= mouse_x <= 110 and 10 <= mouse_y <= 60:
                        car = create_random_car('horizontal')
                        all_sprites.add(car)
                        
                    elif 10 <= mouse_x <= 110 and 80 <= mouse_y <= 130:
                        car1 = create_random_car('vertical')
                        all_sprites.add(car1)
                        
      

        all_sprites.update()

       
        screen.fill(WHITE)

      
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, ((WIDTH // 2) - 150, 0, 300, HEIGHT))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, (HEIGHT // 2) - 50, WIDTH, 100))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (10, 10, 100, 50))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (10, 70, 100, 50))

        
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (WIDTH // 2, 0), (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT), 5)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, (0, HEIGHT // 2), (WIDTH, HEIGHT // 2), 5)

        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
        text = font.render("horizontal", True, BLACK)
        screen.blit(text, (40, 20))
        text = font.render("vertical", True, BLACK)
        screen.blit(text, (40, 80))

       
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

      
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```